# Copy table data into text file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to insert data into text file from select query using SQL Server 2012. But I'm not able to to this please help me.

Code

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "Select RecodLine from WorkDataLoad" queryout "D:\Test.txt" -T -SSubhash-Pc -c -t,'
```

Error

> Starting copy...
>   SQLState = S0002, NativeError = 208
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'WorkDataLoad'.
>   SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unable to resolve column level collations
>
> BCP copy out failed

Comment: Fully qualify? `dbname.dbo.WorkDataLoad`

Comment: It gives invalid object name error. So before you run this script, have you set database like this - Set `USE [YourDB]` or just append dbname in your query

Comment: @AlexK. Same error after try this "EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "Select RecodLine from [dbo].[WorkDataLoad]" queryout "D:\Test.txt" -T -SSubhash-Pc -c -t,'"

Comment: @Subhash replace <dbname> with your database name

Comment: @Subhash - Did you write the name of your database where it says "dbname" ? Like "myOwnLittleDatabase.dbo.WorkDataLoad" ?

Comment: You can use BCP it's easier.  This creates statements for all your tables. SELECT 'bcp '           --bcp
+  QUOTENAME(DB_NAME())+ '.'               --database name
+  QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID))+ '.'  -- schema
+  QUOTENAME(name)                         -- table
+ ' out c:temp'                          -- output directory
+  REPLACE(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),' ','') + '_' 
+  REPLACE(name,' ','')                    -- file name
+ '.txt -T -c'   -- extension, security, 
FROM sys.tables

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :)

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Data NVARCHAR(1000))
DECLARE 
    @AllData NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @FileDest NVARCHAR(100)

--Replace only the path here for example ' >>C:\myfile.txt'',no_output'
SET @FileDest = ' >>E:\test.txt'',no_output'
SET @AllData = ''

INSERT INTO @TestTable VALUES
    ('This is my first row'),
    ('hello from second row')

SELECT @AllData += 
    'EXEC xp_cmdshell ''@ECHO '+Data+@FileDest+CHAR(10)
FROM @TestTable

EXEC(@AllData)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the DataBase mane is missing in the SELECT statement, use query like this:

```
Select RecodLine from DatabaseName.SchemaName.WorkDataLoad
```

Or, you have to provide an argument to specify the database name like:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "Select RecodLine from WorkDataLoad" queryout "D:\Test.txt" -d "DatabaseName" -T -SSubhash-Pc -c -t,'
```